# VS Code change file extension at file save as dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

On some files I need to change standard save as file dialog.
I want to use custom command that executed 'workbench.action.files.saveLocalFile' command with some params that can change availible file extensions.
Where I can find the params if they exist?

Another way:

1. Custom command with showSaveDialog (my own vscode.SaveDialogOptions)
2. Close unsaved editor
3. Open saved file in editor
   At step 2 I use 'workbench.action.closeActiveEditor' command, but I can see confirm dialog (Do you want to save the changes...)

How to remove this confirm?